# How to Automatically merge a branch into another in Github?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to automatically merge commits from master into another parallel branch which is used for different deployment strategy. So essentially whenever there is a change in master I want that change to be merged into one more branch automatically.

Is there a way in Github UI to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Github does support automerge, but [only for Pull Request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request).

You might check out a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) like [action-automerge](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/action-automerge)

> GitHub action to automatically merge the source branch into a target branch every time a change is made.

You can add a GitHub Action workflow to your project in order to enable that "action-automerge".

That being said, maybe you have other approaches which would be simpler than merging `master`/`main`. Using the same branch but with a deployment script able to detect its execution environment would be easier.

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful. I explored action-automerge